# javascript count black spaces as 0?

Tags: javascript, nan

I am building a script that is embedded in HTML to generate a report that extracts information from an internal company system.

The objective is to build some kind of a funnel, making the sum of records in each of the stages. For example, I have:

- Processes in stage 1 = "3"
- Processes in stage 2 = "5"
- Processes in stage 3 = " "
- Processes at stage 4 = "2"
- Processes in stage 5 = " "

However, I have a problem when one of the stages is empty (it is not 0) because there is no stage in that specific process. When I try to add, for example, Stage 1 and Stage 3, it always returns an empty value, while it should give result 3 (3 + 0).

```
<p id="global_calc"></p>
<script>
{ 
var A = Stage1.system.count;
var B = Stage2.system.count;
var total = A + B;
}
document.getElementById("global_calc").innerHTML = "The total of this stage is: " + total;
</script>
```

The Stage.system.count is the internal system's variable that has the number I want to eventually sum with var total.

But, for example, if **Stage1.system.count = 3** and **Stage2.system.count = " "**, **total result in " " instead of 3**. How can I make this to count the black space as a 0?

Comment: If `A` is `"3"` and `B` is `" "`, then `A + B` yields `"3 "`. Are you sure your variables are what you think they are?

Comment: I tried to see what the variables are with typeof and the result was number (Stage1.System.count) and undefined (Stage2.System.count)...

Answer (score 0):

First it's probably worth checking what variables you have; any `number` + " " will always give you a string:

```js
const x = 123 + " "; // "123 ";
const y = 123 + "" // "123"
```

We can see that in practice in your example:

```js
{
var A = 3;
var B = " ";
var total = A + B;
}
document.getElementById("global_calc").innerHTML = "The total of this stage is: " + total;

console.log(("The total of this stage is: " + total).replace(/ /g, '*'))
```

```html
<div id="global_calc"></div>
```

It seems like you're using `undefined` as part of the addition, which returns the value `NaN`:

```js
{
var A = 3;
var B = undefined;
var total = A + B;
}
document.getElementById("global_calc").innerHTML = "The total of this stage is: " + total;

console.log(("The total of this stage is: " + total).replace(/ /g, '*'))
```

```html
<div id="global_calc"></div>
```

We'll need more details to figure out exactly why you're getting `" "` for total.

If you want a function which converts `number -> number` and `" " -> 0` then `Number` would do:

```js
const x = 3;
const y = " ";

console.log(Number(x));
console.log(Number(y));
```